# Is Devise gem support for single user login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

A user named 'user1' signed in at compter a. Then in another computer b, account 'user1' can't sign in, user1 must logout, then user1 can sign in on computer b.

Is devise support for this?

Comment: Can't you simply check if 'user1' is already logged-in before Devise routines are called.

Comment: No, because HTTP is a stateless protocol. Best you can get is logout user1 on computer a when he logs in on another machine (get that working with checking login ip address)

Answer (score 0):

You can add column into users table, which will indicate if user logged in or no. Set it to true when user logs in, and then false when logs out. On user login check this column if its false, then login your user, otherwise show some notification than somebody else using this account.

To avoid situation when user just closes tab without logging off, make rake task that will logout user after some time

UPD: As @Arjan said, you dont even need rake task, you can use devise's module for this

Comment: You don't need a rake task to do that. Devise has a [timeoutable](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Timeoutable) module that signs out a user after a certain amount of time for you.